# Как сделать free() внутри функции, функция не void

Tags: c, утечка-памяти

Есть вот такой код https://github.com/gnuvse/c_git/blob/master/big_num.c

Конкретно интерисуют функции diff_number и reverse_number.
Я в них выделяю память, как эту память потом освободить?
Мне кажется, что это память висит.

Код функций:

```
char *diff_number(int count_digits, char *buf1, char *buf2) {
char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * count_digits);

    for (int i = 0; i < count_digits; i++) {
        if (buf1[i] - buf2[i] < 0) {
            buf1[i + 1] -= 1;
            res[i] = (buf1[i] + 10) - buf2[i];
        }
        else
            res[i] = buf1[i] - buf2[i];
    }

    return res;
}

char *reverse_number(int count_digits, char *buf) {
char *buf_reverse = malloc(sizeof(char) * count_digits);

    for (int i = 0, j = count_digits - 1; i < count_digits; i++, j--)
        buf_reverse[i] = buf[j];

    return buf_reverse;
}
```

valgrind показывает 6 раз память выделена, а в коде всего 5. Еще и 2 ошибки.

```
==20631== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20631==     in use at exit: 1,011 bytes in 3 blocks
==20631==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 1,042 bytes allocated
==20631== 
==20631== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20631==    definitely lost: 1,011 bytes in 3 blocks
==20631==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20631==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20631==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20631==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20631== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20631== 
==20631== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20631== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Странный вопрос. Взять да освободить:

```
char * some = diff_number( ... );
/* ... */
free( some );
```

Comment: Да, только это можно сделать перед return, а результат-то мне нужен, а так я его затру. Тем более я память выделяю внутри функции. Меня интерисует освобаждение именно в функции без потери результат.

Comment: Вы сами-то почитайте, что пишете. "* результат-то мне нужен, а так я его затру*" - это пять баллов! Определиться бы: либо "нужен", либо "затру". Варианта всего два: либо выделяете память внутри функции и возвращаете её как результат. Либо память для помещения результата принимаете аргументом функции (но и в этом случае, скорее всего, она будет где-то выделена динамически и её придётся потом освобждать).

Comment: Ага, я память выделяю внутри функции, если Вы посмотрите на код в топике, то там это есть. Значит когда я возвращаю результат в другую области памяти и делаю free(), то и там и там освобождается?

Comment: Если вы принимаете память для помещения результата, то думать о её освобождении должен тот, кто эту функцию вызывает. Как, впрочем, и в первом случае. Внутри функции никаких освобождений этой памяти быть не должно.

Comment: Значит я все освобождаю. Тогда, если Вас не затруднит, почему valgrind выдает ошибки, память где-то течет?

Comment: Что освобождаете, где? В коде этого не видно. А что касается valgrind -  он может точно показывать проблемные места (пример не ваш, сейчас от балды что-то слепил): http://ato.su/resizer/i/7/1/97432dc9.png

Comment: в топике, приведена ссылка на весь код. Код, который здесь - это только функции.

Comment: Это если пофиксить чтобы собиралось (в `reverse_number()` не объявлена переменная `j`), так что не знаю на чём вы valgrind гоняете. В той же reverse_number() вы выделяете память под `buf_reverse`, вот она и зависает в конечном итоге. Типичный случай: новые значения `buf1, buf2, res`  присвоили, а старые удалить забыли.

Comment: Ну  до кучи - у вас вообще какая-то мешанина. Сначала вы выделяете тпамять размером SIZE в res. Зачем, если она вообще не используется? Потом первый раз её теряете, когда этому указателю присваиваете результат `diff_number()`. Потом - и эту память в помойку, после `res = reverse_number()`...

Comment: Сейчас буду разбираться. в цикле же объявление, не, все собирается и ни одного варнинга. Попробуйте сами

Comment: BTW, это тянет на качественный вопрос с хорошим разбором типичных случаев в ответах. Действительно, создайте новый вопрос. Что-то типа "почему в этом коде течёт память". И весь код привести, он не такой большой. Будет полезно.

Comment: А, у меня куда-то C99 потерялся :) Ага, нормально с циклами.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас так и сделаю. Спасибо. А Вы можете этот вопрос закрыть, все равно новый сделаю?

Comment: *ничего не знаю, ушёл в поля с собаками...*